# Spring MVC passing data when redirecting to default (welcome) page - model gone

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to get this done using Spring MVC: my welcome page is index.jsp located right in my /webapp folder so it can be set as welcome page. This page has a login form. When the login fails, I'd like to redirect to this welcome page (`redirect:/`) and pass an error message which can then be shown using JSTL. The problem is, when I do the redirect the model is gone and the errormessage too. But I can't just return the viewname because the index.jsp is in the webapp folder and my View Resolver is mapped on /WEB-INF/pages/...

Anyone know how I can get this to work? This is what I have so far:

**web.xml**

```
<web-app schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">
    <display-name>TDD oefening</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/springservlet-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**springservlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="be.kdg.prog4.tdd"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
</beans>
```

**My controller method for handling the login**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView login(@RequestParam String username, @RequestParam String password) {
        boolean ok = service.checkLogin(username, password);
        ModelAndView mav;
        if (!ok) {
            mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/");
            mav.addObject("error", "Wrong username or password");
            return mav;
        }

        mav = new ModelAndView("favorites");
        mav.addObject("username", username);
        mav.addObject("isRoot", username.equals("root"));
        return mav;
    }
```

**I would like to display the message after redirect here:**

```
<span id="errormsg" name="errormsg" style="color: red;">${error}</span>
```

All the necessary taglibs are present at the top of the .jsp page and jstl and cglib and such are loaded in my pom.xml.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To persist your model after redirecting, you need to use Flash attributes.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes

Here is an example extracted from the JavaDoc:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String handle(Account account, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
   if (result.hasErrors()) {
     return "accounts/new";
   }
   // Save account ...
   redirectAttrs.addAttribute("id", account.getId()).addFlashAttribute("message", "Account created!");
   return "redirect:/accounts/{id}";
 }
```

And the JavaDoc :)

http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html

EDIT --
To reflect the comment made by @M. Deinum

You could add a simple refresh meta in your index.jsp and add and map a login.jsp page inside your spring application. That will make sure that every navigation done by your users will be controlled by the Spring DispatchServlet.

A lil snipped to illustrate the idea.

index.jsp

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/login" />`

A request mapping defined somewhere in your controllers

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doLogin(Model model) {
    // This return sttm needs to reflect the right path to your login.jsp
    return "login";
}
```

Comment: Which won't work in this case as the `index.jsp` is rendered outside the `DispatcherServlet` hence there is no model.

Comment: Yes I indeed stumbled upon flash attributes but they don't seem to work! Are there any other options? Only thing I found is adding a redirect attribute but then it gets added as parameter to the url and then I have to do `${param["error"]}` in my JSP page, which is not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well... They do work... :) As @M.Deinum raised, you need to to have your login.jsp being controlled by Spring. Then you can use the flash attrs and redirect again to the page. Sure you can do some hackery to make something else working but I believe it's easier to use what is already there. Give me a lil while and I will make a quick example for you.